# Do I need the Nitro server directory in nxut3 for direct server api-call in ssr front-end app?

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nitro

I need to have a wrapper around my API calls in nuxt3 app.
our backend has micro-service architecture and our URLs are like this:

```
`${microservice-domain}/api/${entity}/${route}` // car/api/report/topModels
```

and I need to have a specific config for each microservice and each kind of method(POST, GET, ...).

Now do I have to write my API calls in the server directory? does it send my request to the nitro server and then in the nitro server I have to call my backend API via $fetch? is this best practice?

I have another idea to write a wrapper function to handle all these different routes and then I call them inside of this function and return it to my pages and components.

Can somebody help me to do the best practice?

Comment: Have you read through the documentation? It gives best practice advice there. https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/server

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I wouldn't introduce Nuxt server routes just to re-fetch from (open) external sources. You can easilly do this directly in dedicated client side composables, typically Pinia stores. I find server routes useful when I want to leverage some server-side-only features or to expose my own data endpoints externally. And last but not least **when there are connection secrets** (passwords, API keys) not to be exposed publicly. Then doing it server-side is a must. But many integrations like Supabase only require public key, so it is not always a concern.